# How do I select the first object in an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

If I log an array to the console with `console.log(array)` it looks like this:

```
[]
0: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '000593-1', OLDRS: '16.91', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
1: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '000605-1', OLDRS: '16.91', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
2: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '000641-1', OLDRS: '20.87', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
3: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '0000643-1', OLDRS: '15.91', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
4: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '0000608-1', OLDRS: '1.00', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
5: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '0004463-1', OLDRS: '1.02', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
6: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '0004466-1', OLDRS: '1.02', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
7: {Entry: '1', 0006332: '000627-1', OLDRS: '13.27', RANK: '1', RS: '100', …}
length: 8
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Looks like and array of objects to me. If I try to select the first object, with `console.log(array[0])` the output is `undefined`

What am I doing wrong and how can I select the first ojbect of the array above?

Comment: I believe you have the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120547/array-list-length-is-zero-but-array-is-not-empty

Comment: pushing elements to the array in async way

Comment: try this. ```Object.values(obj)[0]; ``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/how-to-access-the-first-property-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: looks like @KhokimMamarasulov is right. Calling `console.log(array[0])` with a timeout gives the expected result. This should probably be marked as a duplicate